# How to call a procedure by Selection_Change event

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 6 Then Call calc09()
```

Sub calc09() is inside a form code module (frm01)
I tried:

```
If Target.Column = 6 Then Call frm01.calc09()
```

I Also  renamed Sub calc09() - to Public Sub calc09() - without result.
I got an Error message:
Compile error: Sub or function not defined

Comment: What if you put it in a regular module?

Comment: @Tim I placed the Sub inside a regular module, then inside a worksheet code module - without result. When I write two brackets - () - after calc09 - excel delete them. If i try to run the code - I have the compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools - References - Solver check box.

If Solver doesn't appear under Available References, click Browse and open Solver.xlam in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Library\SOLVER